# IOS: iBeacon scanning frequency when phone is locked?

Tags: ios, iphone, ibeacon

If an iBeacon starts emitting (100ms), how long should it takes before a locked iPhone detects it? Let's say the iPhone is very close to the emitting iBeacon but my app is not even running in the background.

In other words, what is the LBE scanning frequency when an iPhone is locked?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have done a lot of research on this subject at Radius Networks.  The answers are complicated, but the executive summary is that their are two tiers of detection:

- **Hardware Accelerated**: The first beacon apps to register the **first 30 beacon regions on the phone** get hardware accelerated detection.  Thisey get background detection **within 5 seconds about 90% of the time**.
- **Software Scanned**: Subsequently registered beacon regions get detections as software allows.  If no other apps are ranging, this is on a fixed 15 minute interval.  Statistics say that the average detection time would be 7.5 minutes for these regions.  The **maximum time is 15 minutes.**

Unfortunately, there is no known way to tell which tier your app will get.  Plan accordingly.

Read more here:

http://developer.radiusnetworks.com/2015/04/21/max-beacon-regions-ios.html

http://developer.radiusnetworks.com/2014/03/12/ios7-1-background-detection-times.html

Comment: So given your answer, in order for the iBeacon to get detected within a couple seconds (hardware accelerated), it needs to be registered within the first 30 iBeacon regions on the phone AND the phone needs to be an iPhone 5 or later. Thanks!

Comment: I believe it can also be an iPhone 4S

Comment: Have you run any of those tests on an Android phone? I would like to know the BLE scanning frequency and average detection time for a beacon when the Android phone is locked. Thanks!

Comment: Fortunately, Android beacon detection code is open source (at least with the Android Beacon Library), so you don't need to reverse engineer anything!  By default on Android 4.3.x-4.4.x, background detections happen in up to 5 minutes (2.5 minutes on average) and on Android 5.x within 5 seconds.  See here:  http://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/battery_manager.html

Answer (score 0):

The documentation doesn't seem to be really specific about the scanning times, and I feel like most of the information one can find is going to be anecdotal.

From my personal research and experience, beacon scanning when the app is backgrounded or inactive is variable on the iPhone's battery level and various other factors. For the most part, in most cases, I've determined that region detection should occur within a few seconds.

With that said, I've noticed that it happens a little faster when the phone is in use, taken out of the pocket, etc. This could be due to the fact that as the phone is moving, scanning is increased to bring the user up to speed and prepare apps for use.

Comment: To give a rough idea, what % of time would you estimate that the iBeacon would be detected within a 5 seconds interval?

Comment: It really depends. I would say around 90-95% of the time if you take your phone out of your pocket when you're in the beacon's range or are using the phone. Probably half that if it stays within the pocket in locked mode.